# Cancel button that only calls javascript and does not call controller update function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have some javascript that shows a form when you click an edit icon. The form has a working button that goes into the controller's update function.

I also have a Cancel button in the form, which goes into the update function. However, I don't want to re-direct or re-render from the update function. Re-rendering would lose other forms that may be shown.

Is there a way to have the button ONLY call the javascript? The javascript gets called, but then it goes into the controller.

Moving the cancel button outside of the form_for works, of course, but then the two buttons are no longer next to each other.

```
  <%= form_for(@guide) do |f| %>
    <%= render 'form_part', test: 'name', field: field, f: f %>
    <%= render 'form_part', test: 'city', field: field, f: f %>
    <%= render 'form_part', test: 'province', field: field, f: f %>
    <%= render 'form_part', test: 'country', field: field, f: f %>
    <%= render 'textarea', test: 'description', field: field, f: f %>
    <p>
      <%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-primary edit-guide-btn" %>
      <%= button_tag "Cancel", class: "btn btn-default edit-guide-btn", 
          onclick: "toggle('#{field}','cancel')" %>
    </p>
  <% end %>
```

Now I realize I will have the same problem on submit. The controller will have to re-render the edit page, and the forms that are shown will be hidden again.

How would I allow a bunch of forms to be shown, each with their own submit buttons. When a submit button is clicked, it would only submit to that form, and leave the others alone, without re-rendering the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make your call to button_tag with `type: 'button'` it should fix your issue with the cancel button.

```
button_tag "Cancel", type: 'button', class: "btn btn-default edit-guide-btn", onclick: "toggle('#{field}','cancel')"
```

For your the part about the submissions, if you want to submit a form without reloading the page, you will probably need to do one of the following:

- Use ajax to submit the form

  - This is probably the most work but gives you more flexibility and achieves your goal of not re-rendering the page
- Submit the form with a `target="_blank"` attribute

  - This will open a new window with the results of the form submission. From the wording of your question, it doesn't sound like you would want to use this method for your use case
- Add a hidden iframe to the page with an id and set the form's target attribute to the id of the iframe

  - This option is a good middle ground if you don't need to do anything with the response but it does have some side effects like adding to the user's history in some browsers which can be confusing when they hit the back button and it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Thanks, the button tag was an easy fix for the cancel buttons. For the submit buttons, Ajax is the way to go, but I'll leave that for version 2!